# Change in energy eigenvalue of Schrödigner-Pauli equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-chemistry

If I apply a uniform magnetic field to a paramagnetic material, I will re-orient the quantum spins of the electrons on the atoms to create a net magnetic dipole moment. When the re-orientation occurs does the wave function change for any one electron? Is there a change in the energy of the system defined by the energy eigenvalue?

Comment: A side-note: The Schrodinger equation isn't directly applicable to magnetic fields, you need to use the [Pauli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_equation).